# Find the Number of Books in each format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query to run for coursework that has to show the number of books for each format.

Here is the table I am trying to query format can be (hardback, softback, audio, ecopy)

[booktable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABhRq.png)

Here is the code I have tried, I am unaware how to expand to include all format types:

```
SELECT format, COUNT(format) FROM book WHERE format = 'hardback' OR 'softback' OR 'audio' OR 'ecopy'
```

I know this is incorrect but it only shows the hardback format and how many hardback books are included.

Comment: You are looking for `GROUP BY`.

Comment: use `format in ('hardback', 'softback'....)`, and use group by

Answer (score 3):

I've decided to write an answer, because you must be wondering what happens in your query. I suppose you think it should either work or fail, but instead it works correctly for one format, but then it doesn't show any other. Why?

Your query works as follows: A where clause consists of a boolean expresssion. This can be multiple sub expressions combined with `AND` and `OR`. Your sub conditions are: `format = 'hardback'`, `'softback'`, `'audio'`, `'ecopy'`. Now, `'softback'` is not really a condition. `format = 'softback'` would be. And here it gets weird. Rather then reporting a syntax error, MySQL wants a boolean, so it brashly converts your string.

It does so in two steps, because a string cannot be converted to boolean, but a string can be converted to number and a number to boolean. Hence the DBMS first converts your string 'softback' into a number. That should fail, but it doesn't obviously. This is the second time we expect a syntax error, but it isn't happening. MySQL takes the liberty to convert non-numeric strings into a zero.

Then MySQL converts this number into a boolean. In MySQL true = 1 and false = 0. So you have: `WHERE format = 'hardback' OR false OR false OR false`. Thus you only get 'hardback' books and count these. As there is just one format you select, it can be shown along with the count. I don't know whether MySQL really detects that this is valid, because the query only selects one format. I find it more likely that you are in MySQL's cheat mode (i.e. you haven't `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'`, which is a bad idea, because by working outside `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode, you tell MySQL to let certain invalid queries pass and muddle through.) So MySQL sees there is a format to be selected, but it must be chosen which row to pick it from, and MySQL muddles through with silently applying `ANY_VALUE(format)`.

What you want is an aggregation (count) with one result row per format. "Per ____" translates to `GROUP BY ____` in SQL. So you want:

```
SELECT format, COUNT(*)
FROM book
GROUP BY format;
```

Comment: What a cool and detailed explanation, appreciate that a lot for such a simple question as this is.

Comment: Wait wait, that query will actually parse successfully?  Man,  MySQL will really allow you to hurt yourself...

Comment: I cannot cast a vote but thanks for such a detailed explanation, this syntax resolved what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `GROUP BY format` at the end of the query.

Answer (score -2):

You have to write select query for each format, seperately!

Comment: This is completely incorrect.

Comment: what will be the correct! @Andrew